# how to resize image from gallery

Tags: android

I want to select image from gallery and send it to Second activity but image is too big  .

I need to resize it and I dont know how to do it:

```
buttonIntent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

method onresult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();  
                try {
                    bitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(Showpic_resumeActivity.this,Showdata_result_resume.class);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
            i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

second activity

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent()
                        .getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        image_resume.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), your_image_loc);//ex:R.drawable.image1
int width=200;
int height=200;
Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
img.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

Comment: ok it work !!  im very happy now :>   thanks you so much ling.s i ll not forget u

Comment: system say i need 15 rep

i dont know how to get a rep in website can u tell me

Answer (score 1):

`Passing bitmaps` from one activity to another activity is `risk`. Best way is just `pass Uri` instead of passing bitmaps from first activity to second and then convert Uri to bitmap when it requires.

Answer (score 0):

***First Collect the URI***

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

***and pass the URI from One Activity to Other***

```
btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(Showpic_resumeActivity.this,Showdata_result_resume.class);
            i.setData(uri );// Passing the URI 
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

***And get Back the URI in Showdata_result_resume Activity***

```
Uri uri=getIntent().getData();
YOUR_IMAGVIEW.setImageURI(uri);// Set URI to your ImageView
```

Comment: i try this but my image not send to nxt activity

Comment: @KaneSmithSillapasit its working for me. please check once or post your code the way you applied my logic.

Comment: yes amit same ur code  acticity second only Uri uri =getIntent().getData(); right ///